# Flutter : java.lang.RuntimeException Logcat

Tags: android, flutter

I made an app

It is a simple app that shows images from Firebase realtime database and allows you to download images by tapping a button.

When testing, it ran without any problems, but when I installed the app on my phone and run it, get error and keeps stopping

I don't know exactly where the problem occurred

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args (LoadedApk.java:1656)
  at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run (Unknown Source:2)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8167)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:496)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open (IoBridge.java:496)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init> (FileInputStream.java:159)
  at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.ImageDownloaderPlugin$CallbackImpl$granted$3.invoke (ImageDownloaderPlugin.java:130)
  at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.ImageDownloaderPlugin$CallbackImpl$granted$3.invoke (ImageDownloaderPlugin.java)
  at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.Downloader.resolveDownloadStatus (Downloader.java:277)
  at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.Downloader.access$resolveDownloadStatus (Downloader.java)
  at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.Downloader$execute$1.onReceive (Downloader.java:30)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args (LoadedApk.java:1646)
  at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run (Unknown Source:2)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8167)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:496)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: 
  at libcore.io.Linux.open (Linux.java)
  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open (ForwardingOs.java:167)
  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open (BlockGuardOs.java:252)
  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open (ForwardingOs.java:167)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open (ActivityThread.java:8044)
  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open (IoBridge.java:482)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init> (FileInputStream.java:159)
  at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.ImageDownloaderPlugin$CallbackImpl$granted$3.invoke (ImageDownloaderPlugin.java:130)
  at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.ImageDownloaderPlugin$CallbackImpl$granted$3.invoke (ImageDownloaderPlugin.java)
  at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.Downloader.resolveDownloadStatus (Downloader.java:277)
  at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.Downloader.access$resolveDownloadStatus (Downloader.java)
  at com.ko2ic.imagedownloader.Downloader$execute$1.onReceive (Downloader.java:30)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args (LoadedApk.java:1646)
  at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run (Unknown Source:2)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8167)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:496)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: @SrilalSachintha uploaded

Comment: Your error is a FileNotFoundException because `ImageDownloader.downloadImage(url,` isn't working

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tested it with galaxy note8, s5 and note10. This problem only occurs on note10... the app keeps stopping but the image is downloaded on the album.

Comment: That's just an Android issue. Not all phones work the same. Dunno what to tell you there

Comment: @OneCricketeer ok thank you for your answer I have to find another way to download images.

Comment: Try a different library - https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

Comment: I second the above answer. CachedNetworkImage works best.